# CircleCi Webdriver Chrome version must be between 70 and 73

Tags: protractor, selenium-chromedriver, e2e-testing, circleci

I've an error on circleci that i'm not able to understand. It says that Chrome version must be between 70 and 73 when using selenium chrome webdriver.

```
[21:58:05] I/downloader - curl -o/home/circleci/project/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.45.zip https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.45/chromedriver_linux64.zip
[21:58:05] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.45.zip
[21:58:05] I/update - chromedriver: setting permissions to 0755 for /home/circleci/project/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/chromedriver_2.45
[21:58:05] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[21:58:05] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[21:58:06] E/launcher - session not created: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615279 (12b89733300bd268cff3b78fc76cb8f3a7cc44e5),platform=Linux 4.4.0-141-generic x86_64)
[21:58:06] E/launcher - SessionNotCreatedError: session not created: Chrome version must be between 70 and 73
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.45.615279 (12b89733300bd268cff3b78fc76cb8f3a7cc44e5),platform=Linux 4.4.0-141-generic x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
    at doSend.then.response (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
    at Function.createSession (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
    at Direct.getNewDriver (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/direct.js:77:33)
    at Runner.createBrowser (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
    at q.then.then (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29)
    at _fulfilled (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
    at /home/circleci/project/node_modules/q/q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (/home/circleci/project/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
[21:58:06] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
```

An unexpected error occurred: undefined

my circleci config file

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:8.11-browsers
    working_directory: ~/project

    steps:
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
            - v1-dependencies-
      - run: npm install
      - save_cache:
          paths:
            - node_modules
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
      - run: npm run lint
      - run: npm run e2e
```

Any idea of what is happening ?

Comment: Refer this: https://discuss.circleci.com/t/session-not-created-exception-chrome-version-must-be-62-0-3202-0/19258/7

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. In `circle.yml`

```
- run:
  name: Install Chrome
  command: |
    wget -q -O - https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
    sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

Other solutions like using `-browsers` docker images does not work now

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a problem specific to Circle CI. I was receiving it on my regular IDE setup. The issue is that your chromedriver no longer matches the browser version.

Steps to fix (I'm using Mac OSX):
 - Upgrade your chrome browser to latest: currently 74
 - Upgrade your chromedriver to latest: you can manually download it from their site, or if installed via `brew cask` just run `brew cask upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

One idea would be to download and install the latest Chrome in the .circleci/config.yml file (similar to [@andriy-baran's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2645167/andriy-baran) comment). However, that might use up your build time unless there's a way to cache the Chrome engine directory together with its dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Chrome version Help -> About Google Chrome.
Download the matching Chromedriver from http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
Should solve the issue.

Comment: check this blog- [protractor-error-resolution](https://khyatisehgal.wordpress.com/2019/05/27/protractor-session-not-created-chrome-version-must-be-between-70-and-73/)